# Swap toolbar on fragment launch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a `NavigationDrawer` and a full screen fragment. Clicking on various items in the `NavigationDrawer` inflates a different fragment in the activity.

I would like to also swap in a different toolbar when launching a different fragment. The reason I want to do that instead of inflating a new menu is that the toolbar I want to swap in is a bit complicated and has things like an EditText in it.

Is there some way to do this either in the activity before inflating a fragment or maybe in the fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include your Fragment specific toolbar in your Fragment's layout so  that it's visible in your Fragment permanently.

Now in the `onStart()` method of your Fragment -

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

This will hide the activity's default toolbar so that it does not overlap with the Fragment's toolbar.

Then again in the `onStop()` method of your Fragment -

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
```

So that the Activity's toolbar is visible again outside that Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

each time you call a fragment use "invalidateOptionsMenu" and using fragment id you can set visibility of menuitems in toolbar... if that is what u need... hope it helps